# Get the text from 1 textbox as filename and parse a path from config file to save video

Tags: c#

while I dealt with JS and HTML, I am not very good with C#
Im trying to modify the example from this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wje_qSW9xZ8
What I want is instead of opening a save menu, to use filename written in a textbox and a path from a config file and start recording without browse menu.
I want to make this a screen recorder, where It records with a filename and a set in a file path.
I know that my question is stupid, but some help will be highly appreciated.
...........
I did this changes

`````````
<TextBox x:Name="box1" Text="{Binding name}"/>
````````
`````
 private string _order;
 public string name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { Set(ref _name, value); }
        }
        string location= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOCATION"];
``````
```````
using System.Configuration;

 private void StartRecording()
        {
            var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.FileName = name;
            dialog.InitialDirectory = location;
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".avi";
            dialog.AddExtension = true;`
`````````

What I am still wondering is how to use
name+location and save save automatically without dialog box
But let's say that the changes I made still suffice.

`````
_writer.Open(dialog.FileName, 
(int)Math.Round(Image.Width, 0), 
(int)Math.Round(Image.Height, 0));
````
`````

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and explain what is not working in it

Comment: Done. I made some changes and now it seem to behave apropriately.
I just wonder how to remove the Dialog box and directly save.
But maybe this way is better, because in any other case I will need to handle exceptions with unavailable or full drive, for example shared and the app may fail.
This is the first thing I try to do in C# in about 8 years. Forgot almost everything from then. Seems like I solved most of the problem myself. Contrary to C or C++ everything seems so painful with C#. Haha.

Comment: At least I learned how to work with app.config.